# submit form with jquery / ajax / php without page refresh. Can't get form value to email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm looking to submit a single form input for a tracking number using jquery/php so that the page doesn't refresh. I am able to submit the form and have the email sent to me but can't figure out what to put in $email_body so it actually emails me the form info. The email will send blank (So I assume email is in the PHP code). Please see below for HTML/JS/PHP:

HTML:

```
    <form id="track-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" size="30" class="form-inline" method="POST">
      <input class="focus" name="tracking" id="tracking" placeholder="tracking code" value="" type="text"/>
      <input class="btn btn-default btn-track" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />  
      <img id="success" style="display:none" src="img/check.png" />
      <br>    
      <label class="error" for="tracking" id="track-error">You must enter your tracking code!</label>  
    </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.error').hide(); 
  $("#track-form").on('submit', function(e) {  


$('.error').hide();
  var track = $("input#tracking").val();
    if (track == "") {
        $("label#track-error").show();
        $("input#tracking").focus();
        return false;
    };   

$.ajax({
  url:'sendtrack.php',
  data:$(this).serialize(),
  type:'POST',
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $("#success").fadeIn(300); //=== Show Success Message== 
   },
});

e.preventDefault(); 

 });
});
```

PHP (WHERE THE PROBLEM IS):

```
<?php

$track = $_POST['tracking'];

$email_from = 'info@website.com';
$email_subject = "New Tracking Info";
$email_body = "Tracking Number: $track".


$to = "email@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

If I leave $email_body as is I get a "500 Server Error". If I leave it blank I get an email with just "email@gmail.com" in it, no tracking number.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: what happens if you hard-code a msg as the email body instead of leaving it blank?

Comment: "500 internal Server Error" shows up in Google Chrome DOM

Comment: @SirBdon Have you tried my suggestion below?

Comment: @SirBdon After testing your code with my answer, I have determined that it's the Ajax that is at fault, it has to be.

Comment: @SirBdon I'm curious, which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$email_body = "Tracking Number: $track".
```

to:

```
$email_body = "Tracking Number: $track";
```

The closing semi-colon was missing. You had a dot in its place.

**You can also try:**

```
$email_body = "Tracking Number: " . $track . "\r\n";
```

**NOTE**:
Using/adding headers as below, will reduce the chance of being mistaken for SPAM.

For example:

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Therefore your new headers would read as:

```
$headers = 'From: $email_from' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

As per the `mail()` function on PHP.net **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php**

Comment: I had to use: "$email_body = "Tracking Number: " . $track . "\r\n";" for it to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SirBdon You're very much welcome, I'm glad it worked out for you, cheers (*Peace*)

Answer (score 0):

your don't have a semicolon in the end

```
$email_body = "Tracking Number: $track".
```

Comment: I get 500 Internal Server Error